# Extract original PNG image from PowerPoint 2019 in full resolution?

Tags: images, resolution, microsoft-powerpoint

In Powerpoint 2019, I am trying to obtain an embedded image in original resoultion. I noticed that, if I click "save as image", the resulting image will have an extremely *low* resolution, far below the resolution of the image file added to the slide.

For example, I added an 1180x760 PNG into a slide. When I later wanted to retrieve it for use outside powerpoint, it had only a resolution of 542x355.

I know that PPTX files are ZIP files, and I have checked, that the original PNG file is included. Unzipping* the Powerpoint file I found the image under

```
(ExtractionDirectory)\ppt\media\image11.png
```

But unzipping the PPTX-file and looking through all the images is bothersome, since they have no semantic names; Saving a single slide as a new presentation and then looking through the unzipped contents of that file may be slightly faster, but not by much.

Is there any better option to get the original file, directly from the GUI?

Bonus points, if it is possible to restore the original file name.

---

A reencoded full-resolution image may also be obtained, by exporting the slide to PDF with the "High Fidelity" image compression option, and subsequently extracting images with `pdfimages`, but possible optimizations (e.g. hand-optimized compression) would be lost in the process.

---

<sup>* Unzipping can be done with Windows board tools by creating a copy of the PPTX file, and changing the file extension from `.pptx` to `.zip`.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To save an image in full-resolution (the same as the original inserted file):

Right click the image and select `Save as Picture...`

[image: Demo picture]

Click the arrow next to `Save` and select `Save Original Picture`

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to seet this save option as default? How to copy the full resolution image to the clipboard from within the presentastion?

Comment: This appears to have been removed (as of 2202, at least)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Larry. I’d welcome an edit request to my answer if you have permission.

Comment: You have to select the original file-format (try a few guesses -- .png, .jpg, etc) in order for the "Save Original Picture" option to become available.

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can drop a pptx onto a cmd file or add it to sendto for right click so here we have a PptX with a high res PNG

[image]

`pptEX.cmd <filename>` (or drag and drop or send to this cmd, you can do similar for docX or xlsX or other zip formats)

```
@echo off
if "%~x1" neq ".pptx" echo not a pptx &goto exit
echo/  &echo   Looking for images in "%~dpn1.pptx" &echo/
tar -tf  "%~dpn1.pptx" "ppt/media/*"
if %errorlevel% == 1 echo/ &echo   There was a problem or no image to be found &goto exit
if %errorlevel% == 0 echo/ &echo   Media File(s) should be extractable do you want me to continue
CHOICE /C YN /M "- Press Y for Yes, N for No"
if %errorlevel% == 2 echo Canceled &goto exit
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
if not exist "%~dpn1\ppt" md "%~dpn1\ppt"
cd /d "%~dpn1"
tar -mxf  "%~dpn1.pptx" "ppt/media/*"
dir "%~dpn1\ppt\media\*.*" | more +2
cd /d "%~dp0"
)
:exit
pause&&exit /b
```

and the results are
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If using the web-version of PowerPoint, you can **Save as ODP**, open in Libre Office, then use "Save..." similar to above.

It even prompts whether you want the original or modified.